# Not able to map Dictionary key to values in Django Jinja2

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates, jinja2

I am unable to map the dictionary key value to the value in the jinja template. below is the block where I was trying to map. so the variable(maji.u_priority) value is a numeric value and I want it to be displayed as P1, P2, etc.

View Function.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from .forms import description





Pri = dict([
    ("1", "P1"),
    ("2", "P2"),
    ("3", "P3"),
    ("0", "Code Red")
])





    


def minc():
    service_now_url = SERVICE_NOW
    request_str = majorinc

    url = service_now_url + request_str

    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers)

    json_str = response.json()

    majinc = json_str['result']

    
    return majinc


    

def home(request):

    t2=incident()
    maji=minc()
    irmt=irm()
    pri=Pri


    form = description()


    return render(request,'index.html', context={'form': form,'maji':maji, 'priority':pri})
```

```
Pri = dict([
    ("1", "P1"),
    ("2", "P2"),
    ("3", "P3"),
    ("0", "Code Red")
])




                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ maji.u_brandprodsvc_affected  }}</td>

                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ maji.u_technical_info|striptags  }}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ maji.u_notification_status  }}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ maji.u_priority }}</td>
```

I was able to achieve same thing in Flask jinja template by doing

```
{% for maji in maji %}
            <tr>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ maji['u_incident_number.number']}}</td>

                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ maji['u_notification_status'] }}-</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ priority[maji['u_priority']] }}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ maji['u_restoration_info']|striptags }}</td>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you share the GitHub repo link? The last resort, I will see myself what's the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/mukulmeister/test, here is a different project, but have a similar issue.

Comment: My [GitHub](https://github.com/sunderamDubey) account link.

Comment: in this as well can't map weather dictionary to <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;">{{ weather.current.temp_c  }} Celcius</td>

Comment: which project should i look for in your github.

Comment: Sorry muks, I haven't seen it yet, I'd see and check it today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `priority` dictionary to map the numeric values, then use [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)
method to access values and pass the key as an argument, like so:

```py
{% for maj in maji %}
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">{{ maj.u_brandprodsvc_affected }}</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">{{ maj.u_technical_info|striptags }}</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">{{ maj.u_notification_status }}</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px;">{{ priority.get(maj.u_priority, 'Unknown') }} </td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, don't give same variable names in for loop for both iterator and instance.

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '(maj.u_priority, '')' from 'pri.get(maj.u_priority, '')' not working

Comment: @Muks Check that the `maj.u_priority` value is not `None`. If it is `None`, you could provide a default value to `Pri.get()` using the second argument. For example, `Pri.get(maj.u_priority, 'Unknown')`. This will return `'Unknown'` if `maj.u_priority` is `None`.

Comment: i forget to mention that dic is not declared in template it's passed via view.

Comment: @Muks Can you share more details in the question by editing?

Comment: @Muks Share your relevant view.

Comment: shared in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252296/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-muks).

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '[maj.u_priority]' from 'priority[maj.u_priority]'

Comment: @Muks Ah, what about when you use it with `get()` method? Can you share the full error traceback by editing the question or in the chatroom?

Comment: Invalid filter: 'maj'